# Protocol types within NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oop, protocols

I am trying to introduce some generics-style approaches from .NET into my iOS development. I am retrieving a list of custom objects of type Example.

I have defined a protocol that Example class implements:

```
@protocol ExampleProtocol
@property(nonatomic,assign) int Id;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *Description;
@optional
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *Icon;
@end
```

I then retrieve my NSMutableArray of Example as follows:

```
id<ExampleProtocol> anExample = [arrayOfExampleProtocols objectAtIndex:0];
```

The problem I have is that `anExample` is always empty regardless of the contents of the NSMutableArray. My ultimate aim is to be able to reference the properties with the following syntax:

```
id<ExampleProtocol> anExample = [arrayOfExampleProtocols objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *test = [anExample Description];
```

Comment: I am willing to put money on the fact that you never initialized your mutable array because if `anExample` were "empty" (I'm assuming you mean `nil`) your code would crash due to an index out of range exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no generics in Obj-C.  The "protocol" is a messaging mechanism.  Please see this post: [No Generics in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848641/are-there-strongly-typed-collections-in-objective-c)