# does objective-c has generic types (and with constraints) similar to c#?

Tags: c#, objective-c, generics, ios6

Example Generic Repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

I am looking to use the repository pattern in model layer of my application and can't seem to find much on the subject when comparing c# generic types to objective-c.

Comment: You do have `@interface IGenericRepository<__covariant T: ConstraintClass> : NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there're no generic types in objective-c.

> Use of generics is closest to the use of id in Objective-C collection classes such as NSDictionary.

you could refer to 
[C# programming introduced to Objective-C programmers](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/chapter-4-c-programming-introduced-to-objective-c-programmers#h3Section20)

and this similar question on SO
[Are there strongly-typed collections in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848641/are-there-strongly-typed-collections-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 7, Objective C and Swift 2 now support Generics.

They are defined  like this 
    `@interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType>` or
    `@interface NSDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType>`

as taken from the header file of NSArray and NSDictionary.
They provide type checking at compile time.