# How to make Xcode produce error or warning in case of generic type mismatch?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, generics, clang

Please consider the following:

```
@interface Test : NSObject

+ (void)testBlock:(void(^)(NSArray<NSString*>*))aBlock;

@end

@implementation Test

+ (void)testBlock:(void (^)(NSArray<NSString *> *))aBlock
{
    aBlock(@[@"Hello", @"World"]);
}

@end
```

and then:

```
[Test testBlock:^(NSArray<NSNumber*>* arr){

        [arr.firstObject unsignedIntegerValue];
    }];
```

it's a crash, but the compiler doesn't even think to warn me, whereas I would like to get an error. Is it even possible? Is there some relevant Clang error or warning I could enable in Xcode in order to make it safer?

UPDATE. I don't want to create another question with a very similar problem. This is really annoying. Take a look:

```
NSArray<NSString*>* strings = @[@"Hello"];

for (NSNumber* num in strings)
{
    [num unsignedIntegerValue];// unrecognized selector crash!!!!
}
```

Not even a warning. What the ...? It's so easy to leave such a code untouched during refactoring. I would really like to make compiler warn me about cases like this one.

Comment: This is all correct. Lightweight generics give very little code safety in Objective-C. They're primarily about improving bridging to Swift. They're very, very "light weight," not just in implementation details (i.e. they have no runtime component), but in functionality. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828076/objective-c-generics-not-working-for-methods-xcode-7-beta-build-7a120f for more discussion.