# How to cast an object to class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to cast objects in objective-c?

For example, I have that object and want to cast it into a class:

```
NSManagedObject *item = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: And what's the problem with that?

Comment: want to cast this object to a class

Comment: use (className *) so simple

Comment: I don't what the problem is; your code should work without modification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast an object in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690748/how-to-cast-an-object-in-objective-c)

Comment: "Cast into a class" is a meaningless term.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you want like this:

```
if ([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]])
{
    NSManagedObject *item = (NSManagedObject *)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}
```

Have a look at [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) first, under `Auto Generating Model Files`, see how author changed `NSManagedObject` to a strongly typed object.

So what will be left for you is:

```
if ([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[Contact class]])
{
    Contact *item = (Contact *)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, instead of casting you can use Strongly Typed Objects. It will save your cast each time you access them.

Comment: I want to cast the object into a class i have it called contact

Answer (score 2):

Yes simply do

```
NSManagedObject *item = (NSManagedObject *)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: NSManagedObject is the name of my class ?

Comment: YES write there name of your class

Comment: As you haven't specified a class I automatically assumed that you wanted to cast to `NSManagedObject *` which is a valid assumption really. But YES your class name would go there.